# How to enhance a cameraphone photo so you can see stars?

Tags: photoshop, astrophotography, cameraphones, stars, smartphone

In the context of star photography, clearly you are not going to get as good of a photo with a smartphone camera as you could with a real camera and a long exposure. However, provided you have taken a photo with what you had on you at the time (in this case a cameraphone), is it possible to enhance such a photo in anyway so that you can at least see where the stars would have been visible to the naked eye?

Comment: Honestly it's unlikely for a host of reasons, generally the signal to noise ratio isn't going to be sufficient.  If you've got one of the latest top-end device with a decent camera like the Lumia 1020 or iPhone 5s then maybe.  Post an example so we can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on the *Sensitivity* of the camera to light compared to the camera's *Signal to Noise Ratio*. If your camera is not capable of gathering enough light from the stars to make the stars significantly brighter than the random noise generated by taking a picture with that camera, then there is no way in post processing to differentiate between small point sources of light such as stars and the random noise that makes some pixels brighter than others.